# Is it possible to make a "block formatting context" with the floating div written in second place?

Tags: css, text, css-float, overflow, block

Having read carefully the article about "block formatting context" (BFC) I still have one basic question which is whether is possible or not to create a BFC, writing in first place the "overflow: hidden" div followed by the floated div (either left or right).

It is easier with an example than with words.

Suppose a CSS layout like this one:

```
.container{
    background-color:#ccc;
    padding:10px;
}
.secondary{
    float:right;
    width:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    margin-left:10px;
    padding:10px;
}
.primary{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

This works fine when the content of the secondary container is not enough long so that mailboxes trim the mail body at a not desired point. When its content is too long, some mailboxes trim the mail content. As a result of that, the only content displayed is indeed the secondary content.

So my question comes as an approach to solve this unfortunate circumstances. I have prepared two JSFiddles. By this way, you can check what I would like to achieve, the means of which for the moment I ignore.

**Working BFC:** http://jsfiddle.net/vnZ5c/2/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="secondary">
        <strong>.secondary</strong>
        <p>This is a secondary content which should not be displayed in any circumstances before the main content. It exists a risk with those mailboxes that trim long emails which would make only visible this secondary content instead of the main content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="primary">
        <strong>.primary</strong>
        <p>This is the primary content, which must appear before anything else, regardless of the length of the secondary content.</p>
        <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tincidunt ultrices leo faucibus condimentum. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus sollicitudin ullamcorper pharetra. Sed sodales sagittis ultricies. Vestibulum feugiat lacus augue, a pellentesque elit tincidunt quis. Vestibulum fringilla aliquet urna, et porttitor velit facilisis ac. Donec euismod fermentum lacus, ac egestas dolor tincidunt vel. Pellentesque at accumsan tortor.</em></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Not working BFC:** http://jsfiddle.net/eZFXH/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="primary">
        <strong>.primary</strong>
        <p>This is the primary content, which must appear before anything else, regardless of the length of the secondary content.</p>
        <p><em>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris tincidunt ultrices leo faucibus condimentum. Suspendisse potenti. Phasellus sollicitudin ullamcorper pharetra. Sed sodales sagittis ultricies. Vestibulum feugiat lacus augue, a pellentesque elit tincidunt quis. Vestibulum fringilla aliquet urna, et porttitor velit facilisis ac. Donec euismod fermentum lacus, ac egestas dolor tincidunt vel. Pellentesque at accumsan tortor.</em></p>
    </div>
    <div class="secondary">
        <strong>.secondary</strong>
        <p>This is a secondary content which should not be displayed in any circumstances before the main content. It exists a risk with those mailboxes that trim long emails which would make only visible this secondary content instead of the main content.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to make a "block formatting context" with the floating div written in second place?

Thank you so much!

*PS: of course I had the temptation of a table layout...*

Comment: Still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, could you go in more detail.

Comment: Is this what you were trying to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/eZFXH/1/

Comment: Hi htmltroll,
Thank you for your comments. What I am trying to do is the content of the left div to flow automatically and adjust to all remaining width left by the right floated div.
When I work with the first JSFiddle (it is important the order in which is written the HTML code: first ".secondary" and then ".primary"), it works as expected. But when I try to reproduce the same behaviour in the second JSFiddle (the opposite order in the HTML code:  first ".primary" and then ".secondary"), the "block formatting text" does not do the trick.
Any ideas?

Comment: No, I am not. That JSFiddle is not what I am trying to achieve. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Can't you just float that in the second example as well?

Comment: Float that? When the floating div is written in second place in the HTML code, then it does not have the desired effect. Have you already tried? Could you get it work? Do you have the JSFiddle?